# How to disable and enable ScrollMagic on window resize ?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm trying to pin the `ul` of a side bar on a full size screen and then, cancel that pin and change it to the parent `nav` of the `ul` at half size screen. 
so basically start with one trigger, target and offset > cancel them when the screen size change > (and) pin a new selector with a new settings.

Answer (score 0):

So here is the solution i got to:

```js
//full screen:
var narrow = new ScrollMagic.Scene({
  triggerElement: '#projects',
  offset: -10,
  triggerHook: 0,
  pushFollowers: false
})

//half size screen:
var wide = new ScrollMagic.Scene({
  triggerElement: '#secondary_nav',
  offset: 0,
  triggerHook: 0,
  pushFollowers: false
})

//enquire.js:  
enquire.register("screen and (max-width:980px)", {

  setup: function() {
    narrow.setPin('#secondary_nav ul').addIndicators().addTo(controller)
  },

  match: function() {
    narrow.remove().removePin();
    wide.setPin('#secondary_nav').addIndicators().addTo(controller);


  },

  unmatch: function() {
    wide.remove().removePin();
    var narrowpin = narrow.setPin('#secondary_nav ul').addIndicators().addTo(controller);

  },

})
```

```html
<nav id="secondary_nav" class=''>
  <ul>
    <li class="btn"><a id='toabout' href="#about">About</a>
    </li>
    <li class="btn"><a id='toprojects' href="#projects">Projects</a>
    </li>
    <li class="btn"><a id='tocontact' class='tocontact' href="#contact_a">Contact</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```